# How to find out a customer's billing date before their contract termination using python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have several customers who get billed every 25th of each month. I want to find out their last billing date before their contract was terminated. Below is a sample from the dataframe:

```
> data = [['Arthur','2019-03-01'],['Bart','2019-02-26'],['Cindy','2019-02-18'],['Douglas','2019-03-31']]

> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','Termination Date'])  
> df
```

Furthermore, below is the expected output:

```
> df['Last Billing Date'] =['2019-02-25','2019-02-25','2019-01-25','2019-03-25'] 
> df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way

```
s=df['Termination Date'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(day=25))
df['New']=np.where(df['Termination Date']>=s,s,s-pd.DateOffset(months=1))

df
      Name Termination Date        New
0   Arthur       2019-03-01 2019-02-25
1     Bart       2019-02-26 2019-02-25
2    Cindy       2019-02-18 2019-01-25
3  Douglas       2019-03-31 2019-03-25
```

Comment: I wonder what's supposed to happen when the termination date is the 25th...

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to subtract a month if the day is before `25`:

```py
import datetime

def last_billing(termination_dt):
    if isinstance(termination_dt, str): # check if not in datetime format
        termination_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(termination_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if termination_dt.day < 25:
        return termination_dt.replace(day=25, month=termination_dt.month-1)
    return termination_dt.replace(day=25)

df['Last Billing Date'] = df['Termination Date'].apply(last_billing)

    Name    Termination Date    Last Billing Date
0   Arthur  2019-03-01          2019-02-25
1   Bart    2019-02-26          2019-02-25
2   Cindy   2019-02-18          2019-01-25
3   Douglas 2019-03-31          2019-03-25
```

If performance is an issue, you `vectorize` the function

```py
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def last_billing(termination_dt):
    if isinstance(termination_dt, str):
        termination_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(termination_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if termination_dt.day < 25:
        return termination_dt.replace(day=25, month=termination_dt.month-1)
    return termination_dt.replace(day=25)

df['Last Billing Date'] = last_billing(df['Termination Date'])
```

Time comparisons:

```py
%timeit df['Last Billing Date'] = df['Termination Date'].apply(last_billing)
## 113 ms ± 365 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df['Last Billing Date'] = last_billing(df['Termination Date'])
## 108 ms ± 397 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in a vectorized way:

```
 df['Termination Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Termination Date']) 

 before_25 = df['Termination Date'].dt.day < 25

 df.loc[before_25, 'Termination Date'] = df.loc[before_25, 'Termination Date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=-1)

 df['Termination Date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=25)).values
```